# zsh terminal shows env variables every time it is open on macOS ventura 13.4

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos-ventura

I have just updated macOS to the latest version 13.4 (BuildVersion: 22F66) and the default terminal, which is zsh, just got all messed up. Now every time I open it, it shows all the environment variables in the beginning. There is also no syntax highlighting anymore.

Has some have gone through the same issue? Not sure if I should reinstall the system's zsh or something like that.

Comment: You have to debug your zsh startup files. Identify the command which displays the environment, and remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you edit your .zshrc file?

Maybe you add some corrupted settings to it. Try to delete your .zshrc file (or better rename it) and open a new terminal. This should reset your terminal to factory settings

Comment: It seems some configuration was poorly added to it. thanks for the advice! manage to find the line after some inspection.